# istringstream & passing arguments to a function

Tags: c++, function, arguments, istringstream

I'm using a do-while loop to get lines of input from the user via an istringstream. Depending on the input it gets, the program should call the co-responding function. Entering X exits the loop.

```
do 
{
    getline(std::cin, input);
    std::istringstream oss(input);
    if (oss >> comm >> m >> n && comm=='I') /* if the input is I followed by  
two integers M & N, create and MxN table using a two dimensional char vector */

    {
        table = tableCreate(comm, m, n, table); 
        tableDisplay(m, n, table);
    }

    std::istringstream oss2(input); /*if the input is F followed by two ints X,Y and char c, 
change the table[y][x] element to c*/

    if (oss2>>comm>>x>>y>>c && comm=='F')
    {
        table = changeElement(x, y, c, table);
        tableDisplay(m, n, table);
    }


} while (input != "X");
```

I'm not going to make this post too long by posting the function definitions, since there's nothing wrong with them. The way I see it, the problem lies in the fact that istringstream can't differentiate between M/N and X/Y for the purposes of the tabledisplay(m, n, table); function.

The first case where the input is I works as intended, but in the second case it looks like the tableDisplay function accepts the two integers from the input stream as its arguments and displays a table of X by Y dimension, while completely ignoring the result of the changeElement function. I tried removing the changeElement function and it's the same thing. I've also tried keeping changeElement but putting tableDisplay outside of the if loop - nothing changes.

How can I make it clear that the integers I enter in case two aren't to be considered as arguments for the tableDisplay function?

Comment: The way to post everything while keeping the post short is to create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see the need for the two string streams. Just use one, read into `comm` and then check what `comm` is. Then read `m` and `n` (in the case `comm == 'I'` *or* read `x`, `y` and `c` (if `comm == 'F'`).

Comment: Will keep this in mind @chris

Comment: As for your problem, I'm not really sure I understand what you mean? It is quite clear from the code that the call to `tableDisplay` is done with the `m` and `n` variables. Since that call is common in both branches, why not move it *out* of the `if` statement bodies, and have it unconditionally last in the loop?

Comment: as I said below when describing the problem, I already tried that. I removed the tableDisplay() outside the if loops but somehow when it runs the second time it still suplements M and N with the two newly entered int values.

Comment: Ah okay I see what you mean, and the error is that you read *two times* from the *same* input. If you combine my two comments you have your solution.

Comment: alright, gonna try doing it like that, thanks for the help

Comment: Oh and you should probably add a check that `comm == 'I'` happens before you call `tableDisplay` so you know that `m` and `n` are initialized.

Comment: I understand that you can make this easier if you add a few checks to the input depending on what the initial command was, but the idea of the exercise was that you'd enter input one whole line at a time, not check what the command is first and than branch off from that , and I'm still not sure how I'd do that. but I appreciate your effort anyway

Comment: But you still would use `std::getline` to read *one whole line at a time*. Then put that line into the input string stream, use the stream to read into `comm`, and then use branching to read the rest of the data form the single input string stream. As long as you read and parse the same line multiple times before you know what the command is you will have this problem.

Comment: Actually there *is* a way to solve your problem using what you do now, but It's really not a way that I recommend. And that way is to read multiple times from the string stream, and rely on the short-circuit evaluation of conditional expressions. I.e. you could do something like `oss >> comm && comm == 'I' && oss >> m >> n`. It is, together with your use of multiple string streams (or even reusing the single string stream) like you do now, quite "ugly" and convoluted and not very streamlined or overly readable or maintainable.

Comment: oh ok, thx for the advice. Gonna look into stringstream a bit to figure out how I can get done what you suggested at first. Just started using it so not sure how it can be handled yet but I'll figure it out